# $batch CRUD (Create) response data empty

Tags: sapui5, abap

I created a batch CREATE call which works fine (table entries are added), but when the call is finished the resulting JSON contains blank values however I can see, via debug, in my DPC_EXT class that er_entity has data in there.

```
oDataModel.submitChanges({
  groupId: "pGroup",
  success: function (data) {
    //HERE -> the JSON entity values in "data" are all blank :(
  }.bind(this),
  error: function (e) {
    //Error
  }.bind(this)
});
```

data:

```
__batchResponses: Array(1)
  0:  __changeResponses: Array(60)
      0: data:
         Currency: ""
         Id: ""
         PhasingMonth: ""
         PhasingYear: ""
         RorId: ""
         Value: 0
```

SAP CREATE_DPC_EXT er_entity (what I expected to see in 'data' above):

```
ID               000000000541
ROR_ID           7
PHASING_YEAR     2019
PHASING_MONTH    01
VALUE            12
CURRENCY         USD
```

Is anyone able to assist?  UI5 version: 1.38

Comment: Hi, when you look at the network request in chrome, does it return any data for that batch operation? i.e. is it SAPUI5 not giving you the data it has, or is it ABAP not sending this data back to you?

Comment: No, Response tab in Network is totally blank (nothing in there at all).

Comment: If the response is blank in the network tab, it looks like the error is in ABAP. Do you know the basis support levels on SAP - SAP_GWFND or IW_FND?

Comment: SAP_GWFND: 740 0018, 
IW_FNDGC: 100 0002

Comment: Maybe there are some SAP notes for this issue - I've been looking and the closest is  `2025868 - Batch operation result empty when one operation is erroneous` but it doesn't seem to be relevant for your version.  Could you post the request that SAPUI5 generates and the response back from the server (from network tab)?

Comment: Request payload:
--batch_f858-c4c1-e123
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_70dd-d70c-e7ae

--changeset_70dd-d70c-e7ae
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST PhasingSet HTTP/1.1
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
x-csrf-token: d-CpqmlcKTHdya2dv3NN0Q==
Accept-Language: en-GB
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 73

{"Id":"0","RorId":"5","PhasingMonth":"01","PhasingYear":"2019","Value":0}

Comment: Out of interest, just did a quick test with only 1 create (no submitbatch) and still nothing in response

Comment: OK, so batch is not at fault - issue is then with create implementation? Can you share the code for the create implementation? Specifically what fills er_entity? I'm thinking maybe it is not the same type and somewhere doing a move-corresponding... What did you get as a response/body or it's http status code?

Comment: Stack comments are not a great place to post code...`DATA: ls_entity TYPE zcl_fi_eng_finance_ror_mpc=>ts_phasing.
    io_data_provider->read_entry_data(
      IMPORTING es_data =
      ls_entity ).
    CALL FUNCTION 'NUMBER_GET_NEXT'
      EXPORTING
       ...
      IMPORTING
        number                  = ls_entity-id
      EXCEPTIONS
        OTHERS                  = 8.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      RETURN.
    ENDIF.
    INSERT INTO ztfi_ror_phasing VALUES ls_entity.
    er_entity = ls_entity.`

Status code is 202.

Comment: INSERT happens, just no response back

Comment: New day, new issue.... I now get a HTTP response in Chrome, but all values are blank: ```--5E1F83830CC8771F3E26EF55DB470FCB0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=5E1F83830CC8771F3E26EF55DB470FCB1
Content-Length:     48399

--5E1F83830CC8771F3E26EF55DB470FCB1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Length: 677
content-transfer-encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 428
location: https://xxxx/sap/opu/odata/sap/Zxxx_SRV/PhasingSet(Id='',PhasingMonth='',PhasingYear='')
dataserviceversion: 2.0```

Comment: To rule out the $batch part of it, send a POST to CREATE_ENTITY. Then, put a breakpoint in the method to verify that er_entity actually has a valid reference to the newly created data.

Comment: You need to post your backend code as well!

Comment: @MikaelG - Data is returned without BATCH

Comment: Then, put a breakpoint in CREATE_ENTITY and follow the code when you do a $batch.

Comment: @orogers - Seems the issue is to do with defer -> When I set cv_defer = true in CHANGESET_BEGIN it falls over.  However, I need this to be deferred as I have ~60 INSERT calls to do (hence the batch)...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there are 2(!) CHANGESET_xxx methods, and I was using the 'other one'....